# MonoTouch.Dialog: When no ImageUrl, default image on StyledStringElement

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I am setting the `ImageUrl` of a `StyledStringElement`, but do not know if the url exists. I'd like to put in an `placeholder image` that is used until the image is successfully downloaded:

```
    var item = new StyledStringElement(n.Title);
        item.ImageUri = new Uri(n.ImageThumbUrl);
```

I get this now:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helpful: http://yusinto.blogspot.ca/2012/05/background-image-downloading-with.html

I copied the `StyledStringElement` to a new `StyledStringElementLoader` and edited this code:

```
    if (extraInfo.Uri != null)
    {   img = ImageLoader.DefaultRequestImage (extraInfo.Uri, this);
        if(img==null)
            img=myLoaderImagePassedToConstructor;
    }
```